# SQL Server update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write an update query for SQL Server, for example:

```
UPDATE x
SET   Col1 = y.Col1,
      Col2 = y.Col2, 
      Col3 = y.Col3
FROM  
    Table1 AS x 
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 AS y ON x.ID = y.ID
```

But I get an error

> Error: near "FROM": syntax error"

I saw same syntax in similar answers, but I can't understand why I get the error

Thanx in advance.

Comment: I think you need `select * FROM Table1 AS x `

Comment: try to use the alias, as in `x.Col1` etc

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your syntax. [It works fine on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec04a/1). What version of SQL Server are you using? Is this the exact query that throws the error?

Comment: doesn't work either , I have tried it...
As i have seen ,ιt's preferable to use only the columns names at set space...

Comment: Is this all the SQL you're executing, as the syntax is correct?

Comment: @GarethD , I'm using SQL SERVER 2008, it's the same query with differents names.Here you see abstract names...

Comment: Query is correct, problem is not reproducible. Closing the question.

Comment: yes it's not reproducible.

Comment: @usr how query is correct?

Comment: @Dimitris try not using alias to update. `UPDATE Table1 SET   Col1 = y.Col1,Col2 = y.Col2, Col3 = y.Col3 FROM  Table1 AS x INNER JOIN Table2 AS y ON x.ID = y.ID`

Comment: @Bharadwaj it is correct in that it works on other peoples machines. You have some other problem not visible here. This is another valid close reason. Impossible to answer.

Comment: @usr I tried `update` before (few months back) with alias, it was not working for me!

Comment: What does it matter? We can only answer from what is posted here. We cannot possibly help you. Realize that, and edit your question to post executable code that demos the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this: I didn't test the code below so, please kindly let me know the result. Thanks

```
UPDATE x
SET   x.Col1 = y.Col1,
      x.Col2 = y.Col2, 
      x.Col3 = y.Col3
FROM  
    Table1 AS x 
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 AS y ON x.ID = y.ID
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had tried this one ,still get the error

Comment: Interesting, what is the error you are getting? The same error?